# Mutating values of subset of columns into percentage format

Tags: r, dplyr

I have generated this summary table based on the df below.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(rep(
 sample(c(2012,2016),10, replace = T)),
 sample(c('Treat','Control'),10,replace = T),
 runif(10,0,1),
 runif(10,0,1),
 runif(10,0,1))

colnames(df) <- c('Year','Group','V1','V2','V3')

summary.table = df %>% 
group_by(Year, Group) %>%
group_by(N = n(), add = TRUE) %>% 
summarise_all(funs(sd,median)) %>%
ungroup %>%
mutate(Year = ifelse(duplicated(Year),"",Year))
```

Is there a way I could display the values related to the `median` columns as percentages?

I did not know how to use `mutate()` and `scales::percent()` for only a subset of columns (I dont want to do it individually, since there will be more columns in the original dataset, making this procedure not practical enough.

What should I have done instead if I wanted to mutate according to a subset of rows?

Thank you

---

**EDIT:**

And if it was like this?

```
summary.table = df %>% 
group_by(Year, Group) %>%
summarise_all(funs(median,sd)) %>% 
gather(key, value, -Year, -Group) %>%
separate(key, into=c("var", "stat")) %>%
unite(stat_Group, stat, Group) %>%
spread(stat_Group, value) %>%
ungroup %>%
mutate(Year = ifelse(duplicated(Year),"",Year))
```

Comment: Why do you wanna show the `median` as percentage? The median is always on the 50% cut of the data.

Comment: The variable itself is a percentage.

Comment: So why not do `summary.table[,7:9]*100`? Or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: I guess it does what I want as well, even if it does not gives me the percentage sign besides

Comment: Why don't you try this? `for(i in 7:9){summary.table[,i] <- sapply(summary.table[,i], function(x) paste(x*100, '%'))}`

Answer (score 1):

We need to use the `percent` wrapped on `median`

```
summary.table <- df %>% 
                  group_by(Year, Group) %>%
                  group_by(N = n(), add = TRUE) %>% 
                  summarise_all(funs(sd=sd(.),median=scales::percent(median(.)))) %>%
                  ungroup %>%
                  mutate(Year = ifelse(duplicated(Year),"",Year))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I could do this if my data set had the medians on the rows and not on the columns?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito  Not clear about your request.  Are you saying that only some rows in a column needs to be transformed? But, if you change that, the class will be only one for that column

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar if I have a table like the one that I just displayed on the question?